# How to add Pass statement in Protractor-Jasmine-typescript html report log

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

I am using Protractor, typescript and jasmine html reporter for logging.
Right now my log is displayed as below.But i want to add log for which steps are passed. Currently it is just showing passed for Passed steps.

```
browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(value){
      if(/report/.test(value)===true)
       {
        fail("Result: URL doesnt works-FAIL");
         }
else
{
 pass("Result: URL works-PASS");
}

    });
```

[image]

I also read somewhere like , we can use because as step explanation but i am not able to add because as below -

expect(userlist.getUsers().length).toEqual(1).because('when a user
object is removed, the list should equal 1');

I also tried this -

```
var since= require('jasmine2-custom-message')

since(function() {
      return 'Actual Message' + ' =/= ' + 'Expected Message';
    }).expect(page.getTitle()).toBe('xyyz');
```

Also tried this -`expect(page.getTitle()).toBe('xyyz','some custom message');`

Basic aim is- it should show Pass- Fail -with statement details

Thanks in advance